# Python-shell - Error: process exited with code 3221225781

Tags: python, node.js, node-modules

I am using node js to connect to python via python-shell. I have followed the documentation but I am getting this error.

Error: process exited with code 3221225781

I have no idea what this means. this is my code as of now

```
    var PythonShell = require('python-shell');
var options = {'pythonPath': './usr/python', 'scriptPath': '/usr', 'pythonOptions': ['-u']}
var pyshell = new PythonShell('script.py', options);

pyshell.send(JSON.stringify(docs));
      pyshell.on('message', function (message) {
        console.log(message);
      });
pyshell.end(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
      console.log('finished');
    });
```

docs is a JSON object i am passing to my python script.
My Python script is:

```
import sys, json, dicttoxml
jsonvar = json.loads(sys.stdin.readlines()[0])
xml = dicttoxml.dicttoxml(jsonvar)
print xml
```

My error is:

```
Error: process exited with code 3221225781
    at terminateIfNeeded (E:\usr\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:100:23)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (E:\usr\node_modules\python-shell\index.js:89:9)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:159:13)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:12)
```

Comment: What is `docs` in the script.  How is your `pyshell` configured? which script are you trying to  run in `pyshell`? Can please provide some more details.

Comment: It is a json object i am passing through node to python